# Emulation in advance CPU Vs Native CPU

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor, linux, emulator

My question is very specific but I might face difficulty framing it well so hope I dont get penalized.

**Background**: Playstation 1, houses 32-bit RISC MIPS R3051 processor, running at 33.8688 MHz with 2 MB RAM, 1MB video RAM. The games targetted for this platform runs smoothly. On the other hand an Ingenic 32-bit XBurst MIPS processor runs at 600MHz, with 128MB RAM, and can support the games for Playstation 1 in emulation.

**Concern**: Now both are MIPS processors, one running at 34MHz and other at 600Mhz, The Ingenic cpu with its specs is an overkill for PS1, however the performance of games running under Ingenic cpu, running embedded linux, is quite poor in various cases.

**Question**: My question is, in such cases, does the performance depends on the fact that one is running an operating system with operating system overhead and the other running proprietary firmware? Or the fact that the emulation software has to perform dynamic runtime compiling which utilizes too much CPU time and hence result in poor performance?

Comment: WHat emulator software are you using?

Comment: PSX4ALL, but regardless of emulator, the performance is similar with all emulators if the game works so I didnt mention the specific emulator

Comment: Emulation is usually a factor of 10 or more slower, yes. Not so much for the processor as all the other hardware that has to be emulated.

Comment: sure but still by that comparison assuming the processing power the game is getting is something like 60MHz which is still larger then the peak frequency of PS1 processor. On top of that PS1 platform uses optical drive while other retro gaming platform such as RetroPi uses SSD.

Comment: Don't assume that since the processors are the same family, this will somehow work better than if they were totally different. PSX4ALL is still *translating* language A into language B (and back), millions of times per second.

Comment: You can't just compare MHz across different platforms as a measure of anything; even within Intel lines it can be misleading. MIPS is a slightly more useful measure. Optical drive speed is only relevant for *loading* games. And looking at the PS1 architecture it has a GPU, which is even harder to emulate and will consume a lot of processing power.

Comment: no simple answer the selected answer by peufeu covers basics on the differences.  generic game emulation is just software trying to execute the instructions, fake the graphics/sound/etc hardware.  Lets call it hand tuned or target specific lets say asteroids, certainly today you could/would simply emulate the instruction set, but the video was also a processor itself, but if you dig in the game "simply" generated a frame, waited for an interrupt so the video end would grab that frame (and draw it).  so you dont have to fake

Comment: counting emulated processor ticks and syncing that to the local machine, you can for that game instead sync the frame updates and because you can easily out run the building of a frame with the emulator to the frame update rate, you dont need to do a whole lot of work.  but this takes game specific knowledge and then do the engineering to make it work well.

Comment: The older and relatively slower the machine the easier it gets with or without details about the game/program.   Without detailed processor knowledge you cant emulate a pipelined processor with caches, etc (see selected answer) and count simulated clock ticks and then sync that, you have to find another way.  and understand there are likely multiple processors in the system you have to do this to.  Your pc has more non-x86 processors than x86 processors in that box for example.

Comment: @old_timer looks you can add value in the form of another answer. I would like to read your take on it. What does "sync the frame updates mean". Plus like your elaboration on " you can easily out run the building of a frame with the emulator to the frame update rate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here:

**1) Speed of light and Causality**

A significant part of modern CPU performance comes from stuff like pipelining and branch prediction. For example it may take 4 cycles to execute one addition, but if the pipeline has 4 stages, it can still execute one addition per cycle, which multiplies throughput by 4. Great!

...Unless the next operation reuses the result of the previous one. Then causality dictates the next operation must wait for the result of the previous one to be available, which introduces pipeline stalls.

The most problematic case of this is conditional branches. The CPU does not know if it has to branch or not until the condition has been calculated, so it has to wait. More pipeline stalls.

An interpreter for any interpreted language needs to ... interpret ... the bytecode which will usually lead to lots of conditionals, switch-case statements, jump tables, etc. This is the worst possible code for any modern CPU which uses branch prediction because the same interpreter inner loop will interpret a different operation every time it is run, so the branch prediction will be wrong most of the time!

Additionally, if the interpreter does not fit into the cpu instruction cache, then it is reeeeally going to suck, because a lot of these mispredicted branches will turn into cache misses and non-prefetched random SDRAM accesses which are slow as hell.

Take-home point: modern pipelined superscalar CPUs are very good at data flow code (apply the same operation many times to lots of data), and terrible at control flow code (lots of tests, jumps, conditions, etc). The latter is a very hard problem, because the performance bottleneck is basically causality and the speed of light (propagation speed of signals), and that's not negotiable.

This is why most CPU emulators recompile the original asm code into the destination cpu asm code... Even if the recompilation is done in a suboptimal way it will still be much better.

Nowadays we'd use LLVM for that. But this is a problem for emulators designed before LLVM...

**2) Custom hardware**

PS1 has a GPU which does polygon texturing, sprites and geometry, and a sound chip. These are programmable custom hardware.

Emulating custom hardware is usually slow, in part because concurrent hardware processes do not map well to sequential software processes. For example hardware can quickly evaluate lots of flags, bits, compute bitwise operations with a bunch of logic gates, etc. Whereas software will have to run lots of tests and conditions, which brings us back to the point 1) above. Worst case, software has to emulate every logic gate one at a time and this will really suck.

Also the geometry processor uses a non-standard fixed point format that is what you'd expect for optimized custom hardware of the era, and that a modern CPU cannot process without lots of bit-twiddling and contorsions... So you'll get code for "if the sign bit is 1 then..." making your math 10x slower (at least) and this cannot be translated into asm code for your CPU since it manipulates data formats that your CPU does not understand.

And all this stuff runs in parallel, synchronized by electrical signals that will have to be emulated too!

**3) Memory**

PS1 has RAM for the CPU, another RAM bank for the GPU, another for the sound chip, and each have various internal caches.

Even if clock frequency is low, all that stuff can be accessed in parallel at the same time... with potentially lots of random accesses... and while modern DDR SDRAM is pretty good at sequential throughput, it still sucks, and will always suck at random accesses because of... you guessed it, speed of light. Commands have to go from the cpu, through a controller, to the SDRAM chips, be processed, come back... therefore, latency.

So I wouldn't be surprised if the main performance bottleneck in your emulator was memory, in other words, cache size.

Comment: This is quite insightful. You mentioned "most CPU emulators recompile the original asm code into the destination cpu asm code" Isnt this what All emulators do? Also I thought LLVM is a cross-compiler and not emulator.

Comment: The jist got from this answer is that "distribubuted processing (parallel) with low speed cpu wins over a single large central processing (sequential) with hight speed cpu with emulation overhead.

Comment: dynamic translation into asm is not efficient, you would want to translate into something like C then let an optimizer do its thing, much more efficient in the long run.  But cant see this being something a game emulator does, if you had that kind of processing power you would just emulate the instructins.

Comment: @old_timer translation to C would require "reverse engineering" the binary code which the game vendor provides and this might be quite challenging. Yes, if this could be done then it is way more efficient.

Comment: You can translate machine code for your emulated cpu into LLVM bytecode and then LLVM will compile and optimize that into machine code for pretty much any CPU on the market. https://llvm.org/

Comment: This is very true it is the same kind of thing as using C, but the translation time for a game would make it unplayable until you have taken the time to play through every possible code path once.  and the dynamic translator has converted all the code, by then the user has given up.  I have seen this work very well (long before LLVM) for business applications where you can tolerate it to avoid having to buy the software again for the new platform, or run software not available on the new platform.

Comment: LLVM JIT is quite fast but yes, indeed this is correct!

Comment: "translating into C" is not something that emulators do. I've not been able to find one that uses LLVM, would you like to cite it?

Comment: I think the PS3 one does. https://rpcs3.net/roadmap

Answer (score 2):

> Background: Playstation 1, houses 32-bit RISC MIPS R3051 processor, running at 33.8688 MHz with 2 MB RAM, 1MB video RAM.

And a custom GPU designed to offload as much as possible from the relatively slow CPU.

> Concern: Now both are MIPS processors, one running at 34MHz and other at 600Mhz, The Ingenic cpu with its specs is an overkill for PS1

It's reasonable to emulate the CPU alone, but if you want to see video out on the screen, you have to emulate the DMA engine and GPU.

> My question is, in such cases, does the performance depends on the fact that one is running an operating system with operating system overhead and the other running proprietary firmware?

No. Performance is bad because your don't have a fast enough system to emulate everything in real-time.

Comment: +1 a comprehensive and to-the-point. It makes so much sense. You made me realize that the heading of the question should be "Platform Emulation in Advance CPU" because its not merely CPU to CPU emulation, its (CPU+GPU) to CPU emulation.

Answer (score 1):

based on comments. since you asked.  I was using the classic stand up arcade machine Asteroids as an example (since I had tried to emulate it I guess over 10 years ago now on a platform that was like 15 times faster in MHZ, still a bucket list item to reverse engineer the code completely).

A generic emulator, see mame, is going to emulate the main processors or simulate whatever the term is.  They will use lean and mean (see the implementations in the source for mame) instruction set simulators for the main code.  Per platform solutions for any other items like graphics processors in various flavors, sound, etc.  Per platform solutions for how to sync game time with the modern/faster platform doing the emulation so the game doesnt run way to fast or be too herky-jerky.  And you get what you get per platform if it is close enough folks will play it if not they wont, some may dive in and improve it, or wait for modern computers to get even faster.

For old cpus like the 6502 in Asteroids with fixed execution times you could if you choose count cpu clocks and try to sync that, n 6502 clocks takes some amount of time, emulate n clocks worth of instructions and wait until a timer/clock on your emulation machine ticks off that amount of time, repeat.  Generic solution works pretty well.

But if you dig into THAT SPECIFIC GAME/PROGRAM you will find that what it is doing is computing the next frame, not unlike many games, say quake for example.  Most games are "simply" computing the next frame, the next video frame, be it the actual pixels as in the old days or the information passed to the graphics processor so it can do it for you, or some blurring of the two.  Asteroids was vector graphics based, it didnt use the guns in the CRT monitor to scan across and blink pixels out like CRTs are generally used.  Instead it could do X/Y lines turn the gun on and draw a line segment.  Since pretty much everything else is horizontal lines of pixels to emulate the vector graphics you have to use a line algorithm to emulate the vector graphics end of it.  The 6502 would compute a "program" if you will that was in a memory shared with the vector graphics engine, a bit would flip and the vector graphics would start using the new program on the next refresh.  Note this is not unlike anything frame based, be it an old game or something very modern, a shared place where the main program drops info to the video side the video side goes through that info over and over again perhaps drawing the pixels on the screen whatever screen means based on that tech.

So this left an opportunity for timing the emulation of the game.  In the asteroids code you will see that the code runs to a point and stops and waits for a shared variable or register to flip.  That item is flipped in a fixed period interrupt.  The game computes the next frame in the vector graphics engine machine code if you will then waits for this interrupt, and repeats that forever.  Inputs are sampled like the buttons and the coin reader and such, and those inputs drive variables that drive the game software to head down some path be it simply move a rock another unit of distance or change from waiting to a coin to waiting to press the start button.

This means you dont need to count cpu instruction clock ticks and try to sync there you can instead sync the video updates if you can simulate the processors machine code in that period of time, all the time, all code paths as programmed in the game.  The older/slower the machine the more likely.  More modern processors with pipes and caches which you really cant simulate (clock accurate) anyway, you dont have to try to be clock accurate on the code portion, instead attack it at the video frame update rate.  You just need to be fast enough to do that.  And dont forget fast enough to process to pixels the graphics/video end of it within the game time rate of a frame as well (for asteroids that was my downfall I didnt have the processing power for both with my initial approaches for the target in question).

Folks like to talk about dynamic translation and some have done it some have not.  Instruction set to instruction set meaning machine code to asm or machine code of the target is not efficient, unless you can/have built in the optimizations.  dynamic is not efficient anyway.  If you are doing a specific translation of one game, not a generic platform emulator, but one specific game, one binary, you are better off trying a static binary translation than a dynamic.  Although it depends on the binary at the end of the day and how clever the programmer was.  Older binaries like asteroids which were likely written in assembly language are harder than something more modern that is compiled.  You will find in some of these code similar to this pseudo code:

r0 = 5;
if r0 = 5 then jump to 0x1234
some data

which taken as two instructions is an unconditional branch, my guess the programmer was going to have an if-then-else but then neutered it.  With variable length instruction sets if you simulate the machine code this all works just fine but if you are doing a static translation then that is closer to a disassembly this could cause problems because the data that follows the "unconditional" branch is not instructions, but that last instruction is conditional so you keep disassembling, and run into problems that have to be fixed by hand examination of the program.

You dont see this in compiled code unless the programmer intentionally put something in to interfere with disassemblers.

I learned from Graham Toal who I suspect worked on some actual product, not necessarily these specific ones but you can/could go to Walmart and get a joystick that plugged into your TV and had one game like Pacman.  I was trying the machine code to asm path, which is possible it is just much harder to eliminate dead code and optimize.  Much better to go from machine code to C where an add instruction might end up looking like

```
res = A + 5;
compute_C_flag(A,5);
compute_N_flag(A,5);
A = res;
cpu_ticks += 3;
```

Which even as written an optimizer can cut down more efficiently than you can, but at the same time the generated program is very very large, so you start to put dead code elimination into your translation, for example you do a quick look at the next instruction, does the next instruction also generate a C and N flag?  Maybe it only messes with the N flag, so you would then

```
res = A + 5;
compute_C_flag(A,5);
//compute_N_flag(A,5);
A = res;
cpu_ticks += 3;
```

for this instruction

for a generic deal you have to build in interrupts and sync points, so after N ticks the system may have some interrupt so somehow you have to solve that for a generic translation.  Lots of fun tricks to learn, I very much enjoyed it.

Later I figured out that for that specific game which did have a fixed interrupt, that interrupt sampled the coin reader and flipped the video frame and I think that was it (maybe sampled the keyboard, but doubt it, that would be a freebie side effect in the main code). So you no longer needed to emulate the interrupt nor count clock cycles, you isolate the code where it stops and waits for an indication that the interrupt happened and you sync there by building into the translation "if the disassembly/translation of the specific instruction is this specific address then add this specific code".   Had to do the same thing for the specific addresses that had the not really unconditional branches or other that caused the disassembler to go off the rails.

what did I mean by sync the frame updates.  So if the game was designed to update the screen/frame/video 30 times a second.  Which is 33.333..ms.  Lets call it 30ms.  That is a unit of time that we can measure/wait for on most processors/computers through a generic timer or a clock timer.  If you can simulate the code from the game that computes a frame in less than 30ms then you have a chance at emulating this game, if you cant then game over your emulation will be slower than the real game on the real platform.  Not all code paths take the same amount of time.  Changing one sprite vs changing the location of 50 sprites, or doing a background animation or changing the background and starting up 50 new sprites, etc.  For a generic emulator you cant play all the games for that platform in a way that covers all code paths, so you have to hope for the best.  And then what you do is pause the simulation at the frame update point until a real wall clock says 30ms has passed, the computer you are running the simulation has hit the next 30ms timer point.  This makes the game that ran on its native platform that had a 30ms per frame rate play on the emulation at a 30ms per frame rate.  The user cannot see any difference so long as you can meet or exceed simulation/emulation of the platform per frame at 30ms or less.  You have to beat the frame rate (have to be 30ms or faster in this example).

That is the most likely way to do an emulation and is usually platform specific as to how that frame rate happens.  Now is the keyboard sampling on the platform at a faster rate or are there other period time based things happening on the native platform that you might also need to sync.

You are generally interested in using video in particular to sync the game execution time to your target emulation machine as that is often the relatively easier place to do it.  But also remember that going back as far as asteroids, the 1970s they were offloading the main cpu running the game code.  It is not an accident that Nintendo games are/were side sliders like mario brothers, the hardware backend on the video did so much work for you they used underpowered (cheap/inexpensive) processors and made up for it with logic on the video side to compensate.  But your emulator is not going to have the exact same hardware so you not only have to compute the frame from the game code perspective in 30ms but you also have to emulate the video hardware acceleration for that frame as well.  as well as any sound hardware if you emulate the sound.

Back in the day games like galaga had multiple cpus which I have not dug in but were no doubt synced on some interrupt, but they must have needed more processing power so like today just threw more processors at it.

Today we offload a lot of the processing to the GPUs, burn multiple CPUs to process the game code, etc.  As each generation passes the next generation emulators have to work much harder.  Or be more clever we have GPUs now so depending on the emulation needed it might be possible to translate a GPU request from a prior platform to an equivalent to the current platform so long as you run the emulation on a platform with a specific GPU or GPU features or library features.  At the same time todays games are written to run on a wide array of platforms we are not running on a 25Mhz 80186 with a fixed speed memory etc etc.  Any major game title released today is expected to run on the wide array of different speeds and different architecture of x86 processors and video cards, yet have the same game play, how do you do that?  make a game timer/turn timer esp if you want multiplayer, and the game has to meet the game turn timer, be it 10ms or whatever, if it is faster than that good the game pauses or the user/game updates the detail of the video, etc.  if slower the game gets choppy (skips frames) or lower res.  so in the future you would sync the same way.

short answer, the emulation wants to meet primarily the video frame rate, or if the game/platform has a game turn timer then you want to meet that.  Make the simulation of the instruction set and the emulation of the rest of the hardware as lean and mean as you can to just barely be functional and accurate.  Older games like the 8 bit standups sometimes all you have is counting instruction ticks and pausing the simulation every N ticks to match what that time would have been in real time.  But some platforms you can attack it at the video directly based on the hardware or game software.

With a more modern pipelined processor with caches you are not going to succeed trying to count cpu clocks through simulation of individual instructions, wont work.

Even shorter answer, if the game machine did X things in Y ms then the emulation needs to do X things in less than Y ms then wait until Y ms have passsed to synchronize the game machine to the emulation machine so that it feels like the game machine.  The more margin the emulation machine has on Y ms the less likely it is to get choppy for the times it cant meet Y ms for X things.

Comment: as always you provide great real-life experience based insight which is worthy of documenting. These little details which you provide make learning more fun as well as help grasp the bigger picture! The code along with the numbers gave more "feel" to the understanding of the subject!